# Menu becomes non-responsive in VB6 code on Windows 10

Tags: drop-down-menu, vb6, windows-10

I have some old VB 6.0 code that I need to get running on Windows 10.  We are not allowed to use Compatibility mode due to security and client refusal issues.

The only problem I am having is that whenever a button is clicked on the interface the menu items (across the top) become unresponsive.  If you mouse over them the shading changes but clicking does not drop down the menu.  Additionally, if I generate a message box pop up and click OK the menus come back to life.

I've tried setting focus to the main form in different situations, tried refreshing the parent and child forms.  Also added a brand new button with no code behind it - not even an empty click event handler - and that button when clicked causes the same issue.

I should also add that the main form is an MDI form with three child forms.  The buttons of course reside on the child forms.

I'm not sure how to proceed with this at this point.  I certainly can't have a message box pop up after every button is clicked.  Has anyone seen this before or have any ideas as to what causes it?

Comment: This is a little hard to understand. I think you need to create a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Are these standard VB6 controls?

Comment: No, they are third party -  'Arcadia' - controls.  Anyway, I believe I have narrowed it down to the radio buttons.  Removing them completely seems to resolve the issue.  Will update when I've confirmed.